# Is there a way to get my page URL to update when changing steps within a Single-Page Ember Application?

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js, single-page-application, adobe-analytics

I have a client of mine who's using a single page application, built in Ember, and they are trying to use analytics to measure dropoff rates at each stage of the form.

I need to try to give them a trigger they can fire when a new stage is reached, in order to update the URL of the page, thereby allowing them to track it in analytics.

Is this even the best way to achieve this?

Hopefully this makes sense, sorry, total lack of Ember knowledge on my side.

Thanks

Comment: Does your route change or not when the stage is changed? If the route is changed, then the URL changes automatically. Otherwise, if the route does not change, do you mean to update the query params?

Comment: Hi Ahmet, 

Looks like the route doesn't change on the way through.

Comment: @SamMay Assuming you are using a DL. Can the application send an event to the DL when the page change occurs?

Answer (score 0):

The code below in a route can update query params of an ember route:

**routes/my-route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams:
  {
    no: {replace: true}
  },

  model: function(dto){
    this.set('no', dto.no);
    return {
      no: this.get('no')
    };
  },

  actions: {
    buttonClicked(){
      this.incrementProperty('no');
      let newNo = this.get('no');
      this.controllerFor(this.get('routeName')).set('no', newNo);
      this.refresh();
    }
  }

});
```

You can take a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d51d4047035ab021daa95a2e64950e26) for complete code.